# Can't import praw

Tags: praw, imp

My program's attempt to load praw 5.0.0.dev0 is failing:

```
>>> import praw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .reddit import Reddit  # NOQA
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 5, in <module>
    from update_checker import update_check
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\update_checker.py", line 11, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 47, in <module>

    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa, rsa
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\rsa.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces import RSABackend
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 510, in <module>
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 39, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    for suffix_item in imp.get_suffixes():
AttributeError: module 'imp' has no attribute 'get_suffixes'
```

I checked imp and found it does have a function `get_suffixes()` but it is marked as deprecated. Searching further I found that importlib should be used instead but have no idea how to do that. pywintypes.py is the file calling `imp.get_suffixes()`. I'm using anaconda3, python 3.5 with everything updated to latest compatible.

Comment: Weirdness. I had updated setuptools but returned the same error. Returned to this from another angle and I could finally import praw from the root folder. Moving to the folder with my own files again triggered the error. I made a new folder, copied my files across, tried again and it worked. A mystery to me (something to do with permissions on that folder? I'm guessing) Anyway, fixed. Idiosyncratic to my machine and system so no help to anyone who may suffer the same.

Comment: OK. Final note: deleted `__pycache__`. All good.